# What is the modern equivalent of reading `/dev/audio`?

Tags: audio, opensuse, recording

Recently my trusty home PC died after 10 years. The ensuing upgrade (from SuSE 10 to OpenSuSE 12.3) was something of a culture shock for me - none of the convenient shortcuts and utilities I had collected work anymore. Today I'm trying to get sound input working again.

I used to record late-night programmes from my local radio station via the line input of my sound card via a tiny little utility that does nothing but open `/dev/audio`, perform a few ioctls and then read bytes from it (and write it to a WAV file with libsndfile). Nothing fancy, just a tiny "autorecord" utility that can record N seconds of sound, and can run through `cron`, without a front-end, without requiring X, and indeed without me having to be logged on. (It was originally adapted from xawtv's `record.c`.)

Now this no longer works. Although my sound card is configured, I can no longer record sound with this tool - in fact, there doesn't seem to be a `/dev/sound` anymore! From what I've gathered, even in 2004 it was a grudgingly-supported legacy feature, while all the cool people were supposed to program against the much fancier and capable ALSA interface.

What is the present-day recommended way of quickly grabbing input from the sound device? Can I re-enable `/dev/sound` emulation somehow? I suppose a third-party program might do the trick as well, as long as it doesn't require me to provide an X session or press buttons in the middle of the night.

Comment: Are you using pulse audio? I expect you are. pacat is pretty handy. Also sox is pretty awesome.

Comment: `/dev/audio` isn't even native to the old OSS sound system of Linux: it was/is a partial implementation (u-law encoding support only) of the corresponding device on old Sun SPARC workstations with the Solaris operating system. The full-featured OSS audio device would have been `/dev/dsp`. ALSA was developed as a response to version 4 of OSS becoming proprietary software in year 2002 or so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out the sound stack developers have anticipated me and written a workaround specifically for situations like mine - I just wasn't able to find it at first.

[Aoss](http://alsa.opensrc.org/Aoss) does exactly the desired thing: it preloads `libaoss.so` and then runs another command line, which will then see a `/dev/dsp` and be able to ioctl/read/write it. So instead of, e.g.

```
autorecord -a -t -d 300 -o violin_concerto
```

say

```
/usr/bin/aoss autorecord -a -t -d 300 -o violin_concerto
```

to have the obsolete tool work just like it used to.

The alternative is to load the corresponding emulation kernel modules, which will create an *actual* `/dev/dsp` and even a `/dev/audio`:

```
# modprobe snd_pcm_oss
# modprobe snd_seq_oss
# modprobe snd_mixer_oss
```

(Of course, the responsible, future-facing thing to would have been to grow up, learn ALSA and pulseaudio programming, and port those old tools to the modern, more complicated sound API. But these days, I no longer have the time for tool-smithing that I used to.)